# Run JUnit Jupiter test with Spring 4.1 and JUnit4 Runner in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, junit5

**Following is my objective**:

- To write Jupiter test case [Test case in Junit5] for Spring code in version 4.1.6.RELEASE.

**I chose to do following** [as Junit5 supports running Jupiter tests on Junit4 runner]:

- Write a Jupiter test case [Test case in Junit5]
- Run with Junit4 Runner [In IntelliJ IDE]

**IDE and Code version Details**:

- Spring Version: 4.1.6.RELEASE
- Java Version: 1.8 [Java 8]
- IDE: IntelliJ Community 2018.3

**Problem i face**:

- When i run the jupiter test case in IntelliJ IDE: 
  i see the test case is run by junit5.
  [IntelliJ trace shows: "com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5"]
  Resultantly, the intended object is not getting autowired/injected in my test class.

I have added both **junit4** and **junit5** to classpath from code.

Can someone suggest how to configure intellij to take only junit4 runner everytime i run test.

**Class which is to be Tested**:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Repository
public class MyClassImpl implements IMyClass {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public String getName(Long Id) {
    String queryString = "some query string";
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);
    List<String> resultList = query.getResultList();
    return resultList.isEmpty() ? null : resultList.get(0);
}
```

**Unittest code: TestClass to test MyClassImpl class**.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {EnvironmentConfig.class, DataConfig.class, WebConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
class MyClassImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private IMyClass myClassObj;

     @Test
    void getAssessmentNameTestIT() 
    {
        if (myClassObj == null)
            System.out.println(" ************ I am NULL ************");
        else {
            System.out.println(" ************ I am NOT NULL ************");
            myClassObj.getName(21L);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Same test case if i write using only Junit 4 [without using any junit5 libraries], the intended object is getting injected.

**Maven Dependencies**:

- junit-jupiter-api       RELEASE
- junit-jupiter-engine    RELEASE
- junit-platform-runner   1.2.0
- junit                   4.10  [test]

**Maven Plugin:**

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-M3</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` only works with JUnit 4, hence the "JUnit4" in the class name.

Thus you cannot use annotations from JUnit 5 (JUnit Jupiter) -- such as `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` -- if you are using a JUnit 4 `Runner`. That will never work.

To use Spring's testing support with JUnit Jupiter, you have to use the `SpringExtension` instead of the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`  or `SpringRunner` -- like this: `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`.

The `SpringExtension` is officially supported as part of the `spring-test` artifact since Spring Framework 5.0: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-junit-jupiter-extension

Note that it is possible to use the original version of the `SpringExtension` with Spring Framework 4.3.x if you use it from my GitHub repository: https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5

In your case, it will not be possible to use Spring's testing support with JUnit 5 if you are still on Spring Framework 4.1.6.RELEASE. You will need to upgrade to at least Spring Framework 4.3.x or, preferably, Spring Framework 5.1.x.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)